# Install Scip optimization

Tags: python, installation, scip

I'm trying install Scip optimization for python and I'm following a video but in the video it is installing Scip Optimization 7, and I'm installing Scip Optimization 8. Then I need to install on prompt too.

> pip install pyscipopt

but it gave me an error:

```
Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.19043.1645]
```

(c) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

C:\Users\matsu>pip install pyscipopt
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyscipopt
Using cached PySCIPOpt-4.2.0.tar.gz (661 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\matsu\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pyscipopt) (0.37.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyscipopt
Building wheel for pyscipopt (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [31 lines of output]
Assuming that SCIP is installed globally, because SCIPOPTDIR is undefined.

```
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\Multidict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\benders.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\benderscut.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\branchrule.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\conshdlr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\cutsel.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\event.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\expr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\heuristic.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\lp.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\nodesel.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\presol.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\pricer.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\propagator.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\reader.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\relax.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\sepa.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  running build_ext
  building 'pyscipopt.scip' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyscipopt
Running setup.py clean for pyscipopt
Failed to build pyscipopt
Installing collected packages: pyscipopt
Running setup.py install for pyscipopt ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for pyscipopt did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [31 lines of output]
Assuming that SCIP is installed globally, because SCIPOPTDIR is undefined.

```
  running install
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\Multidict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\benders.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\benderscut.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\branchrule.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\conshdlr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\cutsel.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\event.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\expr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\heuristic.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\lp.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\nodesel.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\presol.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\pricer.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\propagator.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\reader.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\relax.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\sepa.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyscipopt
  running build_ext
  building 'pyscipopt.scip' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pyscipopt

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I dont know what I did, but somehow it works....

Comment: Does your comment mean that you have resolved your problem? If not and because the error complains about an old version, have you tried updating your Microsoft Visual Studio?

Comment: And if you have indeed resolved the problem, please mark your question as answered/resolved

Comment: Im struggling with the same issue right now. Having updated to the latest build tools, have removed old VS 2017 community edition that I had, reinstalled the latest build tools, rebooted several times etc... Any ideas / suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem.

It was resolved by installing the "Microsoft C++ Build Tools" for **desktop C++ development** which I had not chosen in my earlier attempts.